# Jenkins Maven Build Fails: java.io.IOException - CreateProcess error=2 (The system cannot find the file specified)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

`[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwBTd.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ose2h.png)
error message occurs in the maven i have use both the sh command and bat command for the 'mvn clean install'

```
C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\devops-automation>mvn clean install -e -X
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

```
`java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:159)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1126)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1089)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:252)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:221)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:994)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:506)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.launchWithCookie(BourneShellScript.java:178)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.FileMonitoringTask.launch(FileMonitoringTask.java:134)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.durable_task.DurableTaskStep$Execution.start(DurableTaskStep.java:329)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:323)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:196)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:124)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1225)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1034)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:41)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)``
```

Comment: Please remove link.